# Visual Studio 2013 crashes with an exception - An exception was thrown by a taskscheduler

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 is crashing with an exception - An exception was thrown by a taskscheduler.

I am unable to resolve this issue, searched but could not get any useful information on this.

Need help to resolve it.

Comment: Without more details, it's unlikely you'll find an answer *anywhere*.

Comment: As soon as i start the VS 2013, it is throwing this exception, and VS exits. I am trying to repair the VS2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not even uninstall/repair the Visual Studio. When i clicked on the Visual Studio from the Control Panel, even the uninstall wizard did not come up.

The solution which worked for me is:
When I saw the GAC_MSIL, many dll's were missing, then i copied System.dll, System.Core.dll and System.Reflection.dll into the GAC_MSIL. After copying these dll's , from the control panel the uninstall wizard started, and then i repaired the VS 2013. Then it worked.

I also saw this sort of crash in one of my VMs, in that scenario, i copied the above dll's and VS started working.

Answer (score 1):

many time when we update our .NET Framework then this problem is occurred. Check if you update your version of .NET Framework then uninstall that and also repair visual studio.