# An exception was thrown by a task schedule

Tags: visual-studio-2013

After install visual studio 2013, i have this problem. A window notice was appeared and the message is : An exception was thrown by a task scheduler.
It makes me can not start to use vs. Any body know how to solve this problem ????

Comment: this Question is Answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970632/visual-studio-2013-crashes-with-an-exception-an-exception-was-thrown-by-a-task

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 crashes with an exception - An exception was thrown by a taskscheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970632/visual-studio-2013-crashes-with-an-exception-an-exception-was-thrown-by-a-task)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some method you can try to analyze the issue:

1. Run vs2013 is safe mode - it can be achieved by running Devenv.exe /SafeMode

   If vs2013 is loaded , this mean some VS extensions making the issue - try to remove\disable them all, in addition when in VS reset your VS settings - can be achieved in Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings.

   If not, continue to #2.
2. Use the repair option on your vs2013 installation

   I hope that helps you.